# how do i fix this? i'm not getting the right value for sarah

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python and I'm using python crash course book as my learning material.
I am currently working on the exercises with lists in a dictionary.

[I am trying to do this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jStUz.png)

and I cannot get it right. Here is my code below

```
favoriteLanguages = {
        'jen': ['python', 'ruby'],
        'sarah': ['c'],
        'edward': ['ruby', 'go'],
        'phil': ['python', 'haskell']
        }

for name, language in favoriteLanguages.items():
    if len(language) > 1:
        print(f"{name.title()}'s favorite languages are:")
        for l in language:
            print(f'\t{l.title()}')
    else:
        print(f"{name.title()}'s favorite language is {l.title()}.")
```

[and this is the result that I get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gn91D.png) I cannot get the value for sarah right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are doing wrong in the last line;

```
 print(f"{name.title()}'s favorite language is {l.title()}.")
```

you don't ave to use `l` but `language[0]` as in this case, `language` will have only one element and you want to get that.

So the correct form will be;

```
 print(f"{name.title()}'s favorite language is {language[0].title()}.")
```

Also as you mentioned that you are a beginner, check how to use `else` statement with `for` loop as we can do that in python and you did that here by mistake.